# Evaluating a series of hypergeometric functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I would like to prove (or disprove) the following statement:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\frac{{}_2{\rm F}_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};1\right)}{n!}\right] = \frac{\pi}{2} \left[ \sum_{a=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^a (a!)^2} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{b=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2b}}{\Gamma\left(b+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}\right]
$$
also can be seen as
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\frac{{}_2{\rm F}_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};1\right)}{n!}\right] = \frac{\pi}{2} \bigg[ I_0(1) + L_0(1) \bigg]
$$
Where $I_0(1)$ is the modified bessel function of the first kind and $L_0(1)$ is the modified struve function.

Major brownie points on the line here!

Comment: Out of curiousity, in what context is this emerging?

Comment: Also, have you any evidence for your conjecture?

Comment: @alizter I know it works through calculation thanks to mathematica

Comment: @Semiclassical i forgot exactly to be honest i have where its from written down somewhere but i would have to go looking for it.

Comment: Okay. Part of the reason I'm curious about context is whether or not the identity can be generalized (say, with the hypergeometric function not being evaluated at $1$) and thereby made more natural.

Comment: @Semiclassical where the 1 would be the function to get the one (if my memory isn't playing with me) would be $\cos^2(x)$

Comment: @EricLawson I believe you have a typo in the series over $a$. Should the $a!$ term in the denominator be squared, i.e., $\sum_{a=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^a (a!)^2}$? Otherwise, the series is just $\exp{(\frac14)}$, instead of a bessel function.

Comment: @DavidH yes you are correct, thank you

Comment: The following may be useful: $$I_0(x)+L_0(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(x/2)^k}{\Gamma(1+k/2)^2}.$$ This follows from the series definitions of these two functions ($I_0$ contributes the even terms, $L_0$ the odd terms.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll prove a generalization of the second expression. We first recall Gauss's theorem
$\displaystyle _2F_1(a,b;c;1)=\frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c-a-b)}{\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(c-b)}$ which implies  $$_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};1\right)
=\frac{\Gamma(3/2)\Gamma((1+n)/2)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(1+n/2)}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{\Gamma(1/2+n/2)}{\Gamma(1+n/2)}.$$ Furthermore, applying the duplication formula $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(z+1/2)=2^{1-2z}\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma(2z)$ for $z=1/2+n/2$ yields $\Gamma(1/2+n/2)\Gamma(1+n/2)=2^{-n}\sqrt{\pi}\,n!$. Consequently the hypergeometric function further rewrites to
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{\Gamma(1/2+n/2)}{\Gamma(1+n/2)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{2^{-n}n!}{\Gamma(1+n/2)^2},$$ and we may write the equality

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};1\right)\frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x/2)^n}{\Gamma(1+n/2)^2}.$$

On the RHS, we recall that the functions involved have series definitions
$$I_0(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x/2)^{2n}}{\Gamma(1+n)^2},\quad L_0(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x/2)^{2n+1}}{\Gamma(3/2+n)^2}.$$ But, save for a factor of $\pi/2$, these are just the even and odd parts respectively of the summation just displayed. Consequently we conclude

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};1\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(I_0(x)+L_0(x)\right).$$ Taking $x=1$ yields the identity of interest.

Comment: haha that's pretty sweet, where do you find your identities for this function by the way? i would like to try to get more explicit values for some varying z values of this function? Also with varying z values wouldn't it be very difficult to get values using this method?

Comment: @EricLawson: The relevant identities are referenced in passing on the Wikipedia pages for hypergeometric functions and the Gamma function. The series definitions show up on the pages for Bessel functions and Struve functions. (Mathworld probably has the same references.) And, you may very well be right about it being hard to generalize using this method---but if you want particular generalizations, then perhaps you should ask a question about them. :)

Comment: Okay, whats the best way about developing a solid foundation on this subject, i appreciate your help but i would love to actually learn the material, any personal suggestions?

Comment: Nice answer, +1 (>‿◠)✌

Comment: @EricLawson: I don't have a great explanation for how best to develop a sound foundation. I'd suggest asking it on MSE under the soft-question tag. One thing I should point out is that my use of those identities was rather mechanical: I looked up the series expansions first and noticed that I could put them together. Then I looked up the hypergeometric functions, and upon reading the Wikipedia page was reminded of Gauss's theorem as a special case. (Same kind of story for the Gamma function.)

Comment: @Semiclassical I just realized you can express the rising factorial as a gamma function divided by a gamma function and use identities to simplify / expand to cancel terms out, seems a bit easy when you look at it in that perspective.

Comment: @EricLawson: Neat. I'd encourage you to post that as a solution to your own question, for upvotes and feedback.

Comment: @Semiclassical Well i was using the power series but since thts only when |$z$| < 1 which in this case z = 1 so therefore it cannot work in this particular instance, but in all other instances it would work since z would normally be equal to $\cos^2(x)$

Comment: @Semiclassical it worked out regardless actually

Answer (score 2):

Semiclassical has told me to post an answer to my own question using the technique i have explained to him, now for me to go any further i should state that the original function i am dealing with is:

$
{}_2F_1(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1-n}{2}; \frac{3}{2};\cos^2 (x))
$ 
 therefore using the power series of a hyper geometric function i can say:

$$
{}_2F_1(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1-n}{2}; \frac{3}{2};\cos^2 (x)) = \sum_{a=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac{1}{2})_a (\frac{1-n}{2})_a \cos^{2a}(x)}{(\frac{3}{2})_a a!}
$$

Having $(f(x))_a be the rising factorial therefore with the definition of a rising factorial  as using gamma functions i can state the following aswell:

$$
{}_2F_1(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1-n}{2}; \frac{3}{2};\cos^2 (x)) =  \sum_{a=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+a) \Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2}+a) \Gamma(\frac{3}{2}) \cos^{2a}(x)}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{2}+a)\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2}) a!}
$$

using the following identities i can simplify the function more

$\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) = \sqrt{\pi}$

$\Gamma(\frac{3}{2}) = \sqrt{\pi}/2$

$ \Gamma(\frac{1}{2} + n) = \frac{(2n)! \sqrt{\pi}}{4^{n} n!}$

$$
{}_2F_1(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1-n}{2}; \frac{3}{2};\cos^2 (x)) =  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\frac{\pi(2a)!4^{a+1}(a+1)! \Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2}+a)}{ \pi 4^{a}(a!)^2 (2a+2)!  \Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2})}
$$

$$
=  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\frac{4 \cos^{2a}(x) (a+1) \Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2}+a)}{ a!(2a+2)(2a+1) \Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2})}
$$

$$
=  \frac{4}{2}\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos^{2a}(x) \Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2}+a)}{ 2 a!(2a+1) \Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2})}
$$

$$
= \sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos^{2a}(x)\Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2}+a)}{ a!(2a+1) \Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2})}
$$

Which i know looks very ugly, but when i graphed  this on Mathematica on the interval $ [0,2\pi]$ it was the same result as the function given by Semiclassical (in my specific scenario). therefore you can say that they are equal i suppose?

Comment: That's an interesting generalization, though I find myself surprised that it'd be the same result as in my answer. I may post it as its own question (though if you'd prefer to do so instead, go ahead!)